# How do I return just the matched portion?

Tags: php

```
$string='this dog is done';
preg_match('/^this dog is [^.]+/',$string,$m);
echo $m[0]."\n"; // prints "this dog is done"
```

How do I just get 'done', without the rest of the string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php):

> If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. `$matches[0]` will contain the text that matched the full pattern, `$matches[1]` will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

So:

```
$string='this dog is done';
preg_match('/^this dog is ([^.]+)/',$string,$m);
echo $m[1]."\n";
```